# Either this or that in the sentence

Tags: usage, coordination

To combine these two sentences into one, we can use coordination structures such as 'either...or...'

*You should go to a hospital.

You should go to a clinic.*
As in:

> You should go to either a hospital or a clinic.

But is there only one way which is the shortest sentence?
Or are all these versions also possible?

> Either you should go to a hospital or you should go to a clinic.

> You either should go to a hospital or should go to a clinic.

> You should either go to a hospital or go to a clinic.

> You should go either to a hospital or to a clinic.

Comment: The first two versions sound awkward to me when the two alternatives are exactly parallel (go to A or go to B). We might say "Either I'm going crazy, or that's John Smith over there" (when John is supposed to be miles away).

Comment: I see no reason to use either or at all. You should go to a hospital or clinic. That said the either can go in all those places but is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

With "*either...or*" structures (as with many others), grammatically speaking, anything that is present in the first part can be optionally *elided* from the second. So all of your example sentences have correct grammar.

That said, it's usually best style to elide as many redundant phrases as you can while still maintaining readability.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred version would be one the OP doesn't mention.

> You should go to either a hospital or clinic

as it applies the "either" to the only thing that is different (where you go).
If "go to" is not the same for both parts, then the either would come earlier.

> You should either go to a clinic or get some rest

Answer (score 0):

I add brackets to your 4 variants and see that parallelism is there.  They are, however, wordy.

> [1] Either [you should go to a hospital] or [you should go to a clinic].

> [2] You either [should go to a hospital] or [should go to a clinic].

> [3] You should either [go to a hospital] or [go to a clinic].

> [4] You should go either [to a hospital] or [to a clinic].

You may consider doing away with *either*:

> You should go to a hospital or a clinic.